# web3.admin api doesn't work in external JavaScript code

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, javascript

I'm trying to interact with a private blockchain from a JavaScript code, for that i've provided an RPC address to each node and extended multiple apis using *-rpcapi* . Now if I'm using `geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8546` I'm able to use admin apis in new console, but when I use a web3 object with same address, it doesn't recognize admin api.

```
    var Web3 = require('web3');
    console.log(Web3);
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8546"));
    console.log(web3.eth.accounts);
    document.getElementById("acs").innerHTML = web3.eth.accounts[1];
    console.log(web3.admin);
    console.log(web3.net);
    console.log(web3.personal);
```

It gives perfect response for everything except `web3.admin` for which it shows undefined, am I missing anything? or is it not accessible JavaScript but only in geth attach console.

Comment: Usually admin is not exported with RPC (for security reasons), but you can enable it with the `--rpcapi` option. To use from javascript you need support from web3js, and that depends on what version are you using.

Comment: @Ismael As I mentioned, I enabled admin using `-rpcapi` option and I am able to use it in a separate cmd using geth attach.Only problem is using it through web3, can you specify which version (of web3 or geth ) allows that.

Comment: For web3 v0.20 I've used [web3_extend](https://github.com/yasiriqbal776/web3_extend) or [web3admin](https://github.com/DecentricCorp/web3admin). I don't know if there's an equivalent for web3 v1.0